# Spring Changes Header for Content-Type?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have a Spring and Jersey application and has that line:

```
return Response.ok().header("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8").entity(restTemplate.postForObject(baseURL, entity, String.class)).build();
```

However when I debug at server side I see that Content-Type header is just application/xml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when I debug at server side I see that Content-Type header is
>   just application/xml

I am getting this in my code and during debug I can see the header which is proper.

*Please verify.*

*I don't know but Sorry if I went wrong.*

[image]

Comment: You are right. I had to set another header. In fact code works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a separate header with

```
.header("charset", "UTF-8")
```

Seems like Jersey is reading the header value only upto the `semicolon`.